# C++: Find neighbouring grid points from calibration picture from unsorted list

Tags: c++, grid, jquery-ui-sortable, calibration, neighbours

I do have 4 lists of the x and y coordinates of calibration points. Those are in **no particular order** and not alligned on any axis (they come from a real calibration picture with slight rotation and distortion) but the lists have the same indexing and **cannot be sorted** in such a way that each list is ascending/descending. They also hold no integer values but floating point. I am now trying to find the four neighbouring points for a given point.

E.g. searching for the neighbours of the point [150,150] would return [140,140], [140,160], [160,140], [160,160] (except for them actually beeing more like [139.581239,138.28812]).

At the moment I have to look through all calibration points for each point to check. There are about 500 calibration points.

**Later during the process, I need to know the 4 neighbours for a random point within the 1600x1400 grid for multiple million times. So it is crucial to find those points as fast as possible to avoid calculation time of days or even weeks.**

My first approach was checking each of the ~500 calibration points for each point to check and look at their relative position to the checking point (x_calib > x and y_calib > y would be somewhere in the top, right region of the point) and calculate their distance to it. The closest point in each region (top left, top right, lower left, lower right) would then be the respective neighbour point. That seems not the be efficient at all and takes a lot of time.

The second approach was creating a rainbow table for each of the 1600x1400 points and save the respective neighbours (to be exact, to save the index in the list of coordinates). Later on, the process would check this rainbow table at position [x,y,0], [x,y,1], [x,y,2] and [x,y,3] to get the 4 indices of the 4 neighbour points. Though calculating the rainbow table takes some time (~20 minutes for those ~2 million points), this approach speeds up the later processing. Unfortunatelly, this approach makes it difficult to debug the later steps of the process because it takes this much time before the rest even starts..

I still think there should be room for optimization and I would appreciate any suggestion or help to speed up the whole thing. I allready read about the kd-tree thing but did not quite see the possibility to use it here. I'm hoping that there's an approach for this kind of unsorted (and unsortable) list of points which is more efficient than the rainbow table - or which is at least faster at creating the table.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to serialize your rainbow-table and load it for debugging purposes, so that you don't have to create it anew every time you run your program?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do right now. I'm just pretty new to C++ coding (started 4 weeks ago) and I try to code as efficient as possible. So I hoped there would be some neat way of getting the same result. ;) Until then, I'm going to stay with writing the table to a txt file and read it in the next instance.